# Reporter Builder 2.0

Tags: report, builder

I am developing a simple report in report builder,and i cant fix rows height bug.

When a row has just one line it dont fit the text,and a whiteline appears below it,because others rows in the same grid ,has 2 or more lines.

I try to change properties:"can shrink" and "can grow",but it doesnt solve.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use FastReport .NET, and I can say that in FastReport .NET this works well.